# Unable to return the list that is read from a file(.csv)

Tags: python, csv

I have been learning and practicing python and during which 
I found one error in my program, but I'm unable to resolve. I want to return list of that is retrieved from a csv file. I tried the below code and it returns me an error.

```
import csv

def returnTheRowsInTheFile(fileName):
    READ = 'r'
    listOfRows = []
    try:
        with open(fileName, READ) as myFile:
            listOfRows = csv.reader(myFile)
            return listOfRows
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('The file ' +  fileName + ' is not found')
    except: 
        print('Something went wrong')
    finally:
        #myFile.close()
        print()

def main():
    fullString = returnTheRowsInTheFile('ABBREVATIONS.CSV') 
    for eachRow in fullString:
        print(eachRow)
    return

main()
```

And the error is

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\santo\workspace\PyProject\hello\FinalChallenge.py", line 36,
>   in 
>       main()   File "C:\Users\santo\workspace\PyProject\hello\FinalChallenge.py", line 32,
>   in main
>       for eachRow in fullString: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to solve this problem is to return a *list* from your function. I know you assigned `listOfRows = []` but this was overwritten when you did `listOfRows = csv.reader(myFile)`.

So, the easy solution is:

```
def returnTheRowsInTheFile(fileName):
    READ = 'r'
    try:
        with open(fileName, READ) as myFile:
            listOfRows = csv.reader(myFile)
        return list(listOfRows) # convert to a list
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('The file ' +  fileName + ' is not found')
    except: 
        print('Something went wrong')
```

You should also read [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which is the style guide for Python; in order to understand how to name your variables and functions.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `with open` it closes the file when the context ends. Now `listOfRows` is of the return type of `csv.Reader`, and so is then `fullString` (not a list). You are trying to iterate on it, which seems to iterate over a file object, which is already closed.

Answer (score 0):

As JulienD already pointed the file is alread closed when you try to read the rows from it. You can get rid of this exception using this for example:

```
    with open(fileName, READ) as myFile:
        listOfRows = csv.reader(myFile)
        for row in listOfRows:
            yield row
```

**UPDATE**

Btw the way you handle exceptions makes it pretty hard to debug. I'd suggest something like this.

```
except Exception as e: 
    print('Something went wrong: "%s"' e)
```

This way you can at least see the error message.